Does for every decreasing sequence $a_n$ that converges to 0 hold $0\leq a_n$
my question is if every decreasing sequence that converges to 0 is nonnegative.
My attempt:  Assume that there does exist a decreasing sequence $a_n$ that converges to 0 such that there exists a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $a_k<0$. Since $a_n$ is decreasing we would have that for every $r\in \mathbb{N}$ $k\leq r$ $a_r\leq a_k$ holds. But then we could choose $\epsilon=\frac{a_k}{2}$ and would have only finitely many $a_n$ in this epsilon neighbourhood.
Does this work?
I'm unsure about the step using the epsilon neighbourhood.

You have to take $\epsilon=-\frac {a_k} 2$.

Thank you. Since $a_k$ is less than 0 we need a -.

Every decreasing sequence that converges, converges to $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n.$ If it converges to $0$, then $\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n=0$, and thus $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$.

@Surb Thank you!

@Surb If we consider $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k} $ and we know that this series converges the thoughts above would imply that this series converges absolutely, don't they?

No, for exemple $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Here is a direct proof, not by contradiction. For any fixed $k$ and  $k\le  n$ we have $a_k\ge a_n.$ By taking the limits with respect to $n$ we get $$a_k\ge \lim_na_n=0$$
